# Where do SQL Server text exports get saved?

Tags: sql-server

I'm in SQL Server 2019.  I clicked `Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > General.`

I see that the query results should be saved here:

```
C:\Users\asher\Documents
```

However, when I run a job and try to save the results to a text file, rather than display in the grid, I don't have any file in the path where it should be.  Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "run a job", an Agent Job? That won't return something to *your* My Documents; the file will save where you specified in the Agent Job. The SQl Server Agent Service Account is very unlikely to have access to your "My Documents"; especially if the instance is running on a different host.

Comment: I'm running a query and I want the results saved to a text file.  How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean "saved to text"? As in when you run the query with Result to text, you want to save that? If so, you need to copy and paste from SSMS; there is no "export" function for the result set method.

Comment: There is an option that reads 'Results to Text'.  You can do 'Results to File' or 'Results to Grid'.  It seems like a very simple thing.  I just can't find out how to save the results of a query to a file, instead of displaying it in the grid.  I don't know why there is confusion here.

Comment: Right click pane and select `Save Results as...`? It's confusing because you aren't clear. For example, you use the word "job" but you aren't talking about (SQL Server Agent) Jobs. A "Job" is a specific thing in SQL Server, it's part of SQL Server Agent, as is a scheduled task that runs a sequence of steps. [Create a Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Sorry, I just thought a query was a job.  I tried what you recommended and I'm getting only the first two columns of each query.  I want to export all column names associated with each query.  I checked the box that reads 'include column headers in the result set'.  How can I see all 130 columns instead of just the first 2 columns?  There must be a setting or control for this.

Comment: *"I'm getting only the first two columns of each query"* Then you didn't select all the columns; you selected 2 of them. Select the entire grid (click the empty box in the top left to select the entire grid); SSMS will only export the **selected** columns when using the `Save Results as...` option.

Comment: Ok, got it.  I guess I started thinking it worked some other way, and I kept sticking with that train of thought, which was very wrong.  Thanks for the guidance here!!